# How to enable isis in packettracer

Tags: packet-tracer, is-is

I am using cisco packet tracer 7.0. I am supposed to set isis as the routing protocol. But when try to do this in config mode, the router does not identify the command "router isis". 
When I enter router ? the following is shown:

```
  Router(config)#router ?

  bgp    Border Gateway Protocol (BGP)

  eigrp  Enhanced Interior Gateway Routing Protocol (EIGRP)

  ospf   Open Shortest Path First (OSPF)

  rip    Routing Information Protocol (RIP)
```

There is no isis here.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to issue command #ip router isis

edit: 
Cisco Packet Tracer doesn't support ISIS.

Cisco Packet Tracer Supported Protocols:

Application •   FTP , SMTP, POP3, HTTP, TFTP, Telnet, SSH, DNS, DHCP,
NTP, SNMP, AAA, ISR VOIP, SCCP config and calls ISR
command support, Call Manager Express

Transport • TCP and UDP, TCP Nagle Algorithm & IP Fragmentation,
RTP

Network •   BGP, IPv4, ICMP, ARP, IPv6, ICMPv6, IPSec, RIPv1/
v2/ng, Multi-Area OSPF, EIGRP, Static Routing, Route
Redistribution, Multilayer Switching, L3 QoS, NAT, CBAL
, Zone-based policy firewall and Intrusion Protection
System on the ISR, GRE VPN, IPSec VPN

Network Access/
Interface
•   Ethernet (802.3), 802.11, HDLC, Frame Relay, PPP, PPPoE,
STP, RSTP, VTP, DTP, CDP, 802.1q, PAgP, L2 QoS, SLARP,
Simple WEP, WPA, EAP

[source](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/training-events/netacad/course_catalog/docs/Cisco_PacketTracer_DS.pdf)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but it still says "invalid input"

Comment: Cisco Packet Tracer doesn't support ISIS

Comment: Thanks mate, think I should use something like GNS3. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

clear concept is that cisco packet tracer does not support isis routing protocol

Answer (score 0):

As per the below link ISIS is not supported in packet tracer :

https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/training-events/netacad/course_catalog/docs/Cisco_PacketTracer_DS.pdf